# How to load database external library (assembly) from Entity Framework 6 Code-First?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use EF.6 code-first, and my task is to load external library for SQL Server (Assembly). Assembly is provided as SQL script with binary for example:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [assembyName]
FROM 

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
```

And the assembly is creating properly if I execute the script from Management Studio.

So my question is... Is there a way to do it like good practice or should I read the file and use `Database.SqlQuery<string>` which I want to avoid? I hope there is a another good practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unusual to use SQL CLR in a code-first workflow.  Do you really want to be managing this database schema through migrations?  You can use SSMS or SSDT to manage the database schema and still use the code-first classes and mapping in EF.

If you *did* actually want to do this in your migrations, storing the TSQL script files and reading them when applying a migration seems like  a sensible approach.  Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: Well I do want to avoid that if there is a more sensible way to do that with EF. But seems like maybe i will keep in this direction. The thing is that we use manual migrations and I want this assembly to be part of the code-first workflow to avoid maintaining of the  database manually and require of installation of the assembly .I totally understand that using of SQL CLR with code-first workflow is bad idea and i explained it to project owner, but that was final decision. Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: The other way you might handle this is to add the SQLCLR assembly to your project, and then in your migration serialize the assembly file to a hex string, or upload the bits to a varbinary(max) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've just export the assembly to .sql create script file and include it in my .NET Project.That help to use SqlFile(filePath) method in EF migrations to create a assembly. Thank you David Browne for answer.